# Angular.js Circular Dependency for 2 services

Tags: angularjs

What is the cleanest way to resolve this circular dependency for `StatusTrackerSvc.callNewEvent`? I really wanted to keep these two service files separate.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").factory "StatusTrackerSvc", (
  StatusSvc
  IteratorSvc
) ->

  runEventCheck = (eventId, modalInstance) ->
    IteratorSvc.callNewEvent(eventId, 0).then(->
      StatusSvc.eventCheckSuccess modalInstance
    , (reason) ->
      StatusSvc.eventCheckFailure reason
    )

  eventCheckStart: StatusSvc.eventCheckStart
  runEventCheck: runEventCheck
  eventCheckResetValues: StatusSvc.eventCheckResetValues
```

---

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").service "IteratorSvc", (
  $injector
  $timeout
  ErrorSvc
  $q
  EventSvc
  Configuration
  StatusTrackerSvc
) ->

  checkStatus = (data) ->
    data.Automation.Status isnt "FAILED" and data.Automation.Status isnt "COMPLETEDWITHERROR"

  callNewEvent = (eventId, iteration)  ->
    check = (data, eventId, deferred, iteration) ->
      if iteration is Configuration.CHECK_ITERATIONS
        deferred.reject "The maximum #{Configuration.CHECK_ITERATIONS}
        attempts have been reached in checking status."
      else if checkStatus(data)
        iteration++
        $timeout (->
          StatusTrackerSvc.callNewEvent eventId, iteration
        ), Configuration.TIME_ITERATION
      else
        errorMessage = ErrorSvc.nonSuccess(data)
        deferred.reject errorMessage

    url = EventSvc.getEvent(eventId)
    deferred =  $q.defer()
    url.get().then (data) ->
      if data.Automation.Status isnt "COMPLETED"
        check data, eventId, deferred, iteration
      else
        deferred.resolve "complete"
      deferred.promise



  callNewEvent: callNewEvent
```

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer if you didn't use coffeescript in your example code. You're limiting your potential for getting an answer to a very small percentage of Angular users.

Comment: I agree, I hate coffee script. I am forced to use it. To decompile it here would make it looks even worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").factory "StatusTrackerSvc", (
  StatusSvc
  IteratorSvc
)

angular.module("main.loadbalancer").service "IteratorSvc", (
  $injector
  $timeout
  ErrorSvc
  $q
  EventSvc
  Configuration
  StatusTrackerSvc
```

)

there is your problem "IteratorSvc" requires"StatusTrackerSvc" and he requires "IteratorSvc" you can't shouldn't have that if you need common date, put it in a third service that should do it

Comment: Ya, I thought about that.... but creating a third service for the main service `StatusTrackerSvc"` just to call `runEventCheck` seems like to much breaking up.

Comment: well other thing you can do is in IteratorSvc inject $rootScope and fire an event that can be catch in StatusTrackerSvc to run callNewEvent, anyway, there is no way around it, either restructure your events or include scopes and events for signaling and decoupling, you can also use watchers and flags using $rootScope, but all those are hacks, the actuall solution should be making the scopes not to reference each other